# How to catch I/O exception (exactly I/O, not std::exception)

Tags: c++, exception, io

I tried the example program from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) (with mingw-w64). The program crashed. So I edited it:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    try {
        file.open("not_existing.txt");
        while (!file.eof())
            file.get();
        file.close();
    }
    catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception opening/reading/closing file\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "should not reach this";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now it runs, but prints `should not reach this`, while I was expecting it to print `Exception opening/reading/closing file`.

Why is my expectation wrong?

EDIT: 
since this seems to be an important point, here's the exact version om my compiler: mingw-w64 version "x86_64-6.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-rev1" , i.e. GCC version 6.2

Comment: Could you try using `while (file.good()) {` ?

Comment: @xsami same story. The exception is thrown in `file.open("not_existing.txt");`

Comment: I would recommend `char c; while(file.get(c)) {}` Never loop using `eof()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @Galik thanks, but that's just the example code from http://www.cplusplus.com. I have the same behavior in totally different code.

Comment: You should catch both exceptions by reference. At present you have one by value, one by reference.

Comment: @EJP you're right. The first one is just directly taken from the example, I decided not to change it to keep the changes minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a MingW bug. I get the expected result using MacOS Clang 802.0.42. The expected output being:

> Exception opening/reading/closing file

This might be a known regression: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66145

Comment: @yar You could just download the latest MinGW-w64 (which is GCC 7.1.0). It seems like the bug was fixed in GCC 7.0.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, I'll try that in a few minutes, thanks!